# Overwriting the URL at runtime through JS in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have a page that loads some external script (Ex: abc.com/test.js) by default.
I will create  a bookmarklet that will overwrite that external script with a new URL (Ex: def.com/newTest.js), when the page is loading.

Can any body let me know on how to overwrite the URL at run time in IE11 ...
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean a `<script src="abc.com/test.js">` Tag in your HTML head? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: yeah... we can use Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Something like following (you can merge it to the one line for bookmarklet):

```
var s = document.querySelector("script[src='abc.com/test.js']"); 
s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
s = document.createElement('script');  
s.src = "def.com/newTest.js";
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

Comment: Can I use this at the time of the page load

Comment: If it's placed *after* script tag that should be removed (ideally at the bottom of page) - it *should* work (but I haven't tested it)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Version:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('head').find('script[src="abc.com/test.js"]').attr('src','def.com/newTest.js');
});
```